# Initializing/Adding fixed entries on table creation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework code first, and I have two tables that need to be initialized with fixed entries just on table creation. For example:

Columns for table A:

```
-Id
-Name
```

Columns for table B:

```
-Id
-Name
```

On table creation, I need to add the below information for each table:

For table A:

```
Id Name
1  "Name_A1"
2  "Name_A2"
3  "Name_A3"
4  "Name_A4"
```

For table B should be more or less the same:

```
1  "Name_B1"
2  "Name_B2"
3  "Name_B3"
4  "Name_B4"
5  "Name_B5"
6  "Name_B6"
7  "Name_B7"
8  "Name_B8"
```

so how to achieve this? I have thought to override method Seed and add those registries there (hard-coded) but I do not know if it is the best solution. Maybe in development phase it is a good practise to override this method and add there the information to the tables but once application will be deployed in the customer, maybe it is better to once created the database by entity framework in the development machine, then do an export and import it to the customer computer and finally fill those tables with the fixed entries.

Comment: do you use EF migrations ?

Comment: I am newbie with EF code first, I do not know about EF migrations. I am not using it. I am using an initializer that drop/create database if model changes. Anyway, I will have look at. It seems interesting.

Comment: well, if you use the drop/create way, then use the seed method. With migration, you can add initialization code either in seed, or in one of your Migration (Up / down method)

Comment: And yes, it's interesting ;) But EF 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you and Raphaël mentioned, you can use the `Seed()` method:

```
protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
{
    context.A.AddOrUpdate
    (
        a => a.Name,
        new A { Name="Name_A1" },
        new A { Name="Name_A2" },
        new A { Name="Name_A3" },
        new A { Name="Name_A4" }
    );
    context.SaveChanges();

    context.B.AddOrUpdate
    (
        b => b.Name,
        new B { Name="Name_B1" },
        new B { Name="Name_B2" },
        new B { Name="Name_B3" },
        new B { Name="Name_B4" },
        new B { Name="Name_B5" },
        new B { Name="Name_B6" },
        new B { Name="Name_B7" },
        new B { Name="Name_B8" }
    );
    context.SaveChanges();  
}
```

Using `AddOrUpdate` will ensure no duplicate data is inserted into the database. The first parameter, `a => a.Name`, lets EF identify each entity. The identity could be a PK value of the entity, but if your DB is generating these, you won't know the value, so using `AddOrUpdate` will check to see if the `Name` exists. If it doesn't, a new record will be inserted. If it does find a match, the entity will be updated. It is of course up to you to decide on using something that will uniquely identify each entity.

Comment: My database is generating automatically the Id (PK) so this method is good for me. I have overrided the seed method as you have commented. Also, I am having a look to migration since it seems interesting as well. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use EF Migration to achieve that first you should Enable EF Migration in your project using this command in powershell console :

```
Enable-Migration -ContextTypeName yourContextName
```

above command will create a folder called Migration, then in configuration file you can override seed method

just override seed method :

```
 protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
 {
        context.tableA.AddOrUpdate(
             p => p.Name,
             new tableA { Name = "Name_A1" },
             new tableA { Name = "Name_A2" },
             new tableA { Name = "Name_A3" },
             new tableA { Name = "Name_A4" }
        );

        context.tableB.AddOrUpdate(
             p => p.Name,
             new tableB { Name = "Name_B1" },
             new tableB { Name = "Name_B2" },
             new tableB { Name = "Name_B3" },
             new tableB { Name = "Name_B4" }
        );
 }
```

into above method you can define your look-up data like list of postal codes, list of countrys and ....

Comment: Probably be a bit better to give sample code relating to the question rather than just pasting in a load of code from a `Seed()` method that you've used before.